# How to validate an Ajax Form Submit (remote_form_tag)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, haml

I have an ajax mail form like

```
  - form_remote_tag :url=>mails_path,:condition=>"validate_mail()", :html => {:id=>"mailform",:method => :post, :class => 'ajax',:style=>"padding:15px;" } do |form|
    .gimmespace 
      Naam 
      %br
      = text_field_tag :name,params[:name],:class=>"title required"
    .gimmespace 
      Telefoonnummber 
      %br
      = text_field_tag :phone,params[:phone],:size=>25,:class=>"title"
    .gimmespace 
      Mailadres 
      %br
      = text_field_tag :email,params[:email],:size=>30,:class=>"title required"
    .gimmespace 
      Onderwerp 
      %br
      = text_field_tag :subject,params[:subject],:class=>"title required"
    .gimmespace
      Boodschap 
      %br
      = text_area_tag :message,params[:message],:rows=>10,:cols=>45,:class=>"title required"
    .gimmespace
      = submit_tag "Verstuur",:id=>"mailsubmit",:class=>"sendBtn"
      %button{:onclick=>"$.fn.colorbox.close();"} Annuleer
```

The above code is in HAML. It makes an ajax form submit to a controller. I have to validate the fields before it makes a submit. So, I tried several stuff. I read this article http://hillemania.wordpress.com/2006/09/18/rails-ajax-pre-submit-form-validation/ and made a before callback to a test javascript function to validate. Here is the javascript validating function.

```
function validate_mail() {
        alert("Your Name, Email, Subject and Body Content are Required !");
        return false;

}
```

As per the above function, it returns false any way and the form should not get submitted but, it submits well ajaxically. Is there any other way, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `:condition` option instead of the `:before` option. Something like this:

```
  - form_remote_tag :url=> mails_path, :condition => "validate_mail()", ...
```

Then, if your `condition` function returns false, the form shouldn't be submitted.

Of course, you'll need to modify your `validate_mail()` function actually test that each form field isn't blank:

```
if ($('name').value == '' || $('phone').value == '' || ... ) {
  alert('Something was blank...');
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

My Prototype syntax is rusty - that should get you on the right track though.

Comment: The rails 2.3.8 docs says this ":condition  Perform remote request conditionally by this expression. Use this to describe browser-side conditions when request should not be initiated." .. I did it, but still the form gets submitted... :(

Comment: Can you post the code that gets generated by `form_remote_tag`?